# Excel VBA SQL recordset doesn't refresh

Tags: sql, vba, excel, ado

I am running an SQL query over an excel table: *Table1*.  The query runs ok the first time it is executed. But later, after some changes on *Table1*, when the very same SQL query is run, it keeps returning the same values it fetched the first time.

No matter what I do, it will only 'reset' when I completely close excel and open again.  I assume something is happening with the connection or the recordset, but I can't see the problem.  Can someone please take a look at it and tell me what's wrong?

```vb
Sub createConsolidatedTable()

Dim conn As Object, rs As Object
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim icols As Integer

Application.Calculate

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Temp2").Cells.Clear

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Temp1")
    .Calculate
    Set tbl = .ListObjects("Table1")
End With

Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

With conn
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";" & _
    "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"
    .Open
End With

On Error GoTo CloseConnection

Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

With rs
    .ActiveConnection = conn
    .CursorType = adOpenKeyset
    .Source = getSQL(tbl)
    .Open
End With

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Temp2") 'Destination
    For icols = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
        .Cells(1, icols + 1).Value = rs.Fields(icols).Name
    Next
    .Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs 'Create table with new data
    .ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=xlSrcRange, _
            Source:=.Range("A1").CurrentRegion, _
            XlListObjectHasHeaders:=xlYes, _
            TableStyleName:=tbl.TableStyle).Name = "Table2"
End With


CloseRecordset:
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing

CloseConnection:
    conn.Close
    Set conn = Nothing

    Debug.Print "Finished table creation"

End Sub

Function getSQL(tbl As ListObject) As String
    ' create sql instruction
    Dim SQL As String, SheetName As String, RangeAddress As String
        SQL = "SELECT [Business Area], [Company Type], [SOURCE], [Customer Country], [Product], [Segment]" & _
            ", [Ship Year], [Ship 6M], [Ship 3M]" & _
            ", Sum([Quantity]) AS [Sum Quantity], Sum([Amount LCY]) AS [Sum Amount LCY]" & _
            ", Sum([Out Amount LCY]) AS [Sum Out Amount LCY], Sum([Profit]) AS [Sum Of Profit]" & _
            ", Sum([Out Profit LCY]) AS [Sum Out Profit LCY], [Finished Product]" & _
        " FROM [SheetName$RangeAddress]" & _
            " GROUP BY [Business Area], [Company Type], [SOURCE], [Customer Country], [Product], [Segment]" & _
            ", [Ship Year], [Ship 6M], [Ship 3M], [Finished Product]" & _
        " Union ALL" & _
        " SELECT [Business Area], [Company Type], [SOURCE], [Customer Country], [Product], [Segment]" & _
            ", NULL, NULL, NULL" & _
            ", Sum([Quantity]) AS [Sum Quantity], Sum([Amount LCY]) AS [Sum Amount LCY]" & _
            ", Sum([Out Amount LCY]) AS [Sum Out Amount LCY]" & _
            ", Sum([Profit]) AS [Sum Of Profit]" & _
            ", Sum([Out Profit LCY]) AS [Sum Out Profit LCY], NULL" & _
        " FROM [SheetName$RangeAddress] WHERE [SOURCE]='BACKLOG'" & _
        " GROUP BY [Business Area], [Company Type], [SOURCE], [Customer Country], [Product], [Segment];"

    SheetName = tbl.Parent.Name
    RangeAddress = tbl.Range.Address(False, False)
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "SheetName", SheetName)
    SQL = Replace(SQL, "RangeAddress", RangeAddress)
    getSQL = SQL

End Function
```

Comment: "But later, after some changes on Table1, when the very same SQL query is run, it keeps returning the same values it fetched the first time."... how do you make the changes on Table1?

Comment: Once you've make changes to Table1, do you save the workbook?

Comment: Well, there is a previous sub that copies columns from other sheets and finally creates Table1. The whole table has about 10000 rows. I didn't posted the code, being this too long. I don't save the workbook. Would it help?

Comment: The sql fetches it's data from the copy on disk, not the copy in memory - so yes, you have to save it

Comment: "I don't save the workbook. Would it help?" **YES**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [QueryTables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/querytable-object-excel) which interface with ListObjects and can directly run on SQL queries, refreshing each time. In this way you can avoid the need for ADO connection and recordset objects and even building column headers.

```vb
Sub BuildQueryTable()
On Error GoTo ErrHandle
    Dim constr As String
    Dim tbl As ListObject

    Application.Calculate

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Temp1")
        .Calculate
        Set tbl = .ListObjects("Table1")
    End With

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Temp2")
        .Cells.Clear
        .Activate
    End With

    constr = "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" _
               & "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";" _
               & "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Temp2").ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, _
                                           Source:=constr, _
                                           Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable        
         .CommandText = getSQL(tbl) 
         .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table2" 
         .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False 
    End With

ExitHandle:
    Exit Sub

ErrHandle:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "RUNTIME ERROR"
    Resume ExitHandle
End Sub

Function getSQL(tbl As ListObject) As String
   ' same as before ...
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Parfait.  I didn't know about QueryTables, and seems easier than what I did.  I expected this to be much faster too, but the improvement in speed was not as great as I thought

Comment: Underneath the hood, both versions probably do the same ADO connection and data retrieval but this is more compact and hopefully aids in your refresh quandaries. Also, performance may be data-specific. I'd advise using an actual database like Excel's sibling, Access, to take advantage of indexes and query plans.

Comment: Just one more question, @Parfait... When I use your code with QueryTable, a connection remains open and prevents to save and close the file because is currently in use.  How can I avoid this?

Comment: Well, just for the records. I dont know if it is the **best** solution, but i did:`For Each conn In ThisWorkbook.Connections  
        conn.Delete  
    Next conn`

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the solution was as simple as adding `ThisWorkbook.Save`. Thanks Vityata, CLR and Harassed Dad, you saved me.